# Print git branch name, commit hash, and as little else as possible

Tags: git

I would like a git command to print the current commit's branch name (assuming it has one, i.e. it's the tip of a branch), the commit hash (in the usual 7/8-char short form, ideally), and nothing else. If this is not possible, I'd settle for 'as little else as possible'.

There are a number of commands to do one or the other in various forms; `git rev-parse --short HEAD`, `git branch --show-current`, and I've tried some more exotic things like `git show-branch --current --list` hoping to find a useful set of options for them. None seem to exist.

I want to use this both as something I can give a short alias to quickly check in the shell, and as something I could put into the default shell prompt; both so that I am more aware of what exact code I had active when I ran tests etc. Brevity is therefore very important.

Comment: Simething like `git show --no-patch --format=tformat:'%D %h'` maybe?

Comment: If you don't want the `HEAD` plus comma-space, you might have to pass thru something like `sed` or `perl` or similar to get rid of it; I don't seem to be able to eliminate it. But I'm not expert at this, so maybe there's a way

Comment: Shorter (but the same): `git show -s --pretty='%D %h'`

Comment: Yeah, piping could work; I tried `git show -s --pretty='%D %h' | ruby -e 'puts gets.sub("HEAD, ", "")'` and it worked, but I wouldn't recommend it because it's slow.

Comment: Just write your own command that runs `git symbolic-ref` and `git rev-parse` (with appropriate options and appropriate error handling). This can be a ~5 line shell script. Install that shell script as `git-xyzzy` in your `$PATH` and run `git xyzzy` and Git will run your script, which does what you want because you wrote it. (For put-in-prompt purposes you don't even need to bother with this, just edit your $PS1-setter, assuming you're using bash or zsh.)

Comment: ...'just', huh?

Answer (score -1):

To see local branch names run `git branch`. To see all the remote branch names, you could use `git branch -r`. If you have the hash for a commit, you can use the `git show command` to display the changes for that single commit. When you want all the commits printed, `git log` command is used to view the commit history and display the necessary information of the git repository. This command displays the latest git commits information in chronological order, and the last commit will be displayed first.

Comment: That's not even slightly an answer to the question asked.